# How to send verification code in sms using php

Tags: php, sms

I have website and I want to verify user mobile number. How can I do that? Is there any site for sending message to the user mobile number. Please let me know.

Comment: Give a minute here http://phpmaster.com/implement-two-way-sms-with-php/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many sites providing `bulk sms` you can  use `google`, below is the list of some websites which are in my knowledge,

1. http://msg91.com
2. https://www.springedge.com
3. http://www.bulksms.com/
4. https://www.textlocal.in

Answer (score 1):

You need to purchase the API code from the mobile operators.

Or you can do that by paying for a service for true SMS.

use emails where available like `98955*****@tmomail.net`

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/939/sms_email_cingular_nextel_sprint_tmobile_verizon_virgin/

or use curl to sms from each providers web site where available.

Here are few more link to get the code for sending the mobile SMS:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/send-sms-script/

http://www.nowsms.com/doc/submitting-sms-messages/send-sms-text-message-with-php

Answer (score 1):

You need use SMS APIs(gateways), check these services
http://www.clickatell.com/